# PowerBI: Substraction between two measures (calculated based on 'dates in period') with two different date slicers

Tags: powerbi, dax

A little bit of background: I'm trying to figure out how to substract two measures (provided below) from each other to be displayed in a table portraying the change based on the different dates. Please check out the picture for a bit of introductory context.

So far I've succeeded in creating the correct measures for calculating all of the 'trades' made up to a specific trade date, while also filtering the trades with a maturity date only from that specific trade date onwards.

The two measures below are nearly identical and only differs by using other date tables so I am able to select for each of my two slicers. In the beginning I had only one measure, and would just 'Edit interactions' for the two tables provided by the picture, but I duplicated it all to create another slicer because I thought I could just subtract two measures and be done with it.

**Measure 1:**

```
TRADES_MEASURE = 
VAR ReferenceDate = [MaxSelectedDate]
VAR PreviousDates = 
DATESINPERIOD(
    'Previous Date'[Date],
    ReferenceDate,
    -18,
    YEAR)
VAR FutureDates =
DATESINPERIOD(
    'Maturity previous date'[Date],
    ReferenceDate+1,
    50,
    YEAR)
VAR Result =
CALCULATE(
    COUNT('INTEREST TRADES'[TRADEID]),
    REMOVEFILTERS('Date'),
    KEEPFILTERS(PreviousDates),
    REMOVEFILTERS('Maturity date'),
    KEEPFILTERS(FutureDates),
    USERELATIONSHIP('Date'[Date],'Previous Date'[Date]),
    USERELATIONSHIP('Maturity date'[Date], 'Maturity previous date'[Date]))
Return 
Result
```

**Measure 2:**

```
TRADES_MEASURE_2 = 
VAR ReferenceDate = [MaxSelectedDate 2]
VAR PreviousDates = 
DATESINPERIOD(
    'Previous Date 2'[Date],
    ReferenceDate,
    -18,
    YEAR)
VAR FutureDates =
DATESINPERIOD(
    'Maturity previous date 2'[Date],
    ReferenceDate+1,
    50,
    YEAR)
VAR Result =
CALCULATE(
    COUNT('INTEREST TRADES'[TRADEID]),
    REMOVEFILTERS('Date 2'),
    KEEPFILTERS(PreviousDates),
    REMOVEFILTERS('Maturity date 2'),
    KEEPFILTERS(FutureDates),
    USERELATIONSHIP('Date 2'[Date],'Previous Date 2'[Date]),
    USERELATIONSHIP('Maturity date 2'[Date], 'Maturity previous date 2'[Date]))
Return 
Result
```

**Solution request**

If I attempt to create a measure that simply subtracts the two measures It doesn't perform the calculation correctly because I have two date slicers it needs to take into account. For instance if I select both date slicers to 'Interact' with the table it doesn't seem to calculate it correctly when I make a simple measure performing 'Measure 1 - Measure 2'.

Visually I just need the calculation: 'Table 1'[AMOUNT] - 'Table 2' [AMOUNT], but the way my measure is setup makes it a bit more complicated.

Visual: Tables

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

I realised that by simply adding

```
REMOVEFILTER('Date 2')
REMOVEFILTER('Maturity previous date 2')
```

to the `CALCULATE` function in **Measure 1** and likewise

```
REMOVEFILTER('Date ')
REMOVEFILTER('Maturity previous date')
```

to the `CALCULATE` function in **Measure 2**, it then successfully took into account both of the slicers without filtering dependent on only one slicer.

Cheers!